# How to enter BIOS menu?

Tags: multi-boot, uefi, efi

Laptop Fujitsu LH532.

After an unsuccessful attempt to install Arch Linux, I cannot enter the BIOS menu of the laptop. It just beeps, power keeps being on, but it doesn't load anything and does not provide any output.

During the Linux installation, I played a bit with the EFI partition of the HDD and removed several old boot entries with efibootmgr, but that's it.

Before there was Windows on this laptop and again instead of BIOS after F2/F12 I arrived to some windows loader menu.

Now I cannot load from a USB drive and I have only access to half-dead Linux, but the system console is operational.

How can I understand what is going on and how to make the machine able to boot from a flash drive?

Comment: The method and key is the same. Accessing the firmware has nothing to do with the installed OS. It could even have a blank drive. So, before anything else, check your user's ,amual to confirm how to access the firmware.

Comment: Already did, the manual says F2. F2 leads just to a black screen.

Comment: There's really nothing else. However, if you can reach at least Arch's Grub menu *and* if you installed it correctly in UEFI mode then you'll have an entry to access UEFI settings in the Grub menu itself.

Comment: How I can reach it? It loads the system without showing the menu.

Comment: So, if it boots - I was under the impression it didn't - you can also use `efibootmgr`, at least to boot external media (should be possible to reboot to UEFI settings as well) and you can make Grub visible by editing the options.

Comment: "I cannot enter the BIOS menu of the laptop. It just **beeps**," That is often an indication that a password is required. Often a BIOS requires that a password be set to access advanced features. Did you or someone else set one??

Comment: Perhaps it helps to have  a bit more time for manual selection:  `efibootmgr -t 30` will set the time to continue to 30 seconds. // To get the BIOS Boot Menu, the `F9`-key (hit during boot time) is often the key to access it (to select the USB stick)

Answer (score 0):

You hit a bug in Fujitsu's UEFI implementation, which (together with a few edge cases in the Linux kernel and in efibootmgr) ended up [wiping out the hidden boot menu entries](https://blog.timschumi.net/2024/01/20/ah532-bios-investigation.html) that are used to boot into the setup menu.

This can often be remediated by shorting the `CL1_CL2` contact under the RAM slot to clear the BIOS settings (which regains access to booting from arbitrary devices), followed by using the [Fujitsu-provided BIOS update tool](https://support.ts.fujitsu.com/) (runs from a FreeDOS live-USB) to flash a clean copy of the UEFI (which brings back the "BIOS Setup" option in the boot menu and the ability to press the F2 key during boot).

Alternatively, if your installation of Linux is working fine, you can use [this tool](https://github.com/timschumi/ah532-biostools/) to reset the broken boot entries to their original values from a running system. Please take note of the disclaimer and the list of supported configurations first.